# Compress recorded video for android 10 & 11

Tags: android, kotlin

I check many android compress library to compress video in android 10 & 11
But I didn't get any library or any solution to compress video

In the new update, we can not use WRITE Permission in the manifest. Is there any solution or any library to compress video without use permission?

Comment: Of course you can ask for write permissions in manifest and at runtime for an Android 11 device. But not needed as it is implicitly granted to you already.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the reply, But can you give me more detail about that I don't want to give requestLegacyExternalStorage ="true" in the manifest.